# A Label in a Frame in a window won't stretch, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to display

- a window
- with a single `Frame`
- and a `Label` in the `Frame` which would stretch to the whole width of the window

The following code

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
# first column of root will stretch
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# a frame in root
upper_frame = tk.Frame(root)
# first column of upper_frame will stretch
upper_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
upper_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

# a label in upper_frame, which should stretch
mylabel = tk.Label(upper_frame)
mylabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
mylabel.configure(text="hello", background="blue")

root.mainloop()
```

displays

[image]

Why isn't the `Label` stretching to the whole width of the window but is just as wide as the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `sticky` option when you call [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) (`e` = east, `w` = west). Otherwise the widget in the cell is center-aligned.

```
upper_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
..
mylabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is the relationship between `sticky` and `.columnconfigure()`? My understanding was that `.columnconfigure()` would "tell" the child widget to expand. Now I wonder (and wildly guess) if it is "tell" (as in "you must expand as much as possible") or "allow" (as in "you can expand as much as possible, but you must make something in order to do so (this the `stick`)).

Comment: @WoJ, `rowconfigure`, `columnconfigure` is about height, width ratio of the cell. `sticky` is about alignment. Specifying `sticky` with `W`,`E` or `N`,`S` will make the widget stretch to fill the cell.

Comment: @WoJ, See [The Tkinter Grid Geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) for more information.

Comment: I read the docs and found that a column would not stretch if `width=0` (which is the default). I was not aware that, in addition to `.columnconfigure`, the content of the widget must make an effort to stretch (via `sticky`). It is now clear.