# I can't for the life of me get this ttk / tkinter separator to expand

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have to write a program for some coursework I'm doing, and I chose to do an A-Level revision game to help others. I'm trying to get use a ttk separator to split up the area of the window where the game part occurs, and the area of the window where the question sits. My window is split up into 3 frames; one with 4 labels in, one with 4 buttons in and one with a ttk.Separator widget and a label. I cannot get the separator however to span the whole window.

I've been looking around and testing things, but nothing seems to work. I've looked at these two previous posts in terms of on this website:

[ttk.Separator set the length/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924785/ttk-separator-set-the-length-width)
[A Label in a Frame in a window won't stretch, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596354/a-label-in-a-frame-in-a-window-wont-stretch-why)

but neither of these solutions seemed to fix my problem, and I'm now out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
main_revision_game_question_frame = Frame(parent_window, bg='#c2f0f0')
main_revision_game_question_frame.pack()
main_revision_game_question_frame.grid_propagate(1)
main_revision_game_question_frame.config(width=screen_width, height=40)

separator = ttk.Separator(main_revision_game_question_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
separator.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')

question_label = Label(main_revision_game_question_frame,
                               text='     Placeholder text for a question goes here!    
                             \n######################################################',
                               bg='#c2f0f0', fg='#ff2824', font='"Open Sans" 26 bold')
question_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

main_revision_game_question_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
main_revision_game_question_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

This is the code I've ended up with upon trying to combine a few solutions, and this is how it looks:

[image]

You can see the separator is there, but it does not stretch across the frame. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator is expanding to fill the frame, but the frame hasn't been configured to fill the space it has been given.

You need to expand the frame. One way to do that is to use the `fill` option of `pack`:

```
main_revision_game_question_frame.pack(fill="x")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
main_revision_game_question_frame.pack(fill="both")
```

so the frame fills the whole space it is given

Comment: Brilliant thanks, this solved my problem too. Always good to know several solutions to the same problem. :)

Comment: Just remember `fill="both"` expands the frame in the x and y axis. Which for example affects the behavior of the frame when resizing the window. The solution of Bryan Oakley is a little bit more restricted since it only expands the frame in the x axis.